# Max flow, in case of s = t

Tags: algorithm, max-flow

I was reading about [the max flow problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem) on wikipedia. I was curious that does the problem description allow s to be equal to t (the source to be equal to the sink). I know that if s =t , the answer has to be 0. However, assume I am writing code to solve this problem. Should my code handle this special case or does the problem description prohibit this.

Comment: That's not something we can decide. Most descriptions I have seen tend to explicitly state `s != t` as a precondition, but of course it depends on what *your* problem description says.

Comment: But wikipedia does not. Does it?Moreover, the pseduo code for edmond karp on wikipedia handles this special case. Can you read the problem description on wikipedia and Edmond karp's pseudo code on wikipedia and let me know if they state s!= t

Comment: Why would the wikipedia description be relevant? If this is homework, the relevant source is the text of your assignment. If this is for a library, you have to decide how to handle it (return 0? throw exception?) and document it.

Answer (score 2):

If s = t, you can push infinite amounts of flow from s to t since we don't need to use any of those pesky capacity-constrained arc things that limit the amount of flow we can push.

Whether your code needs to handle this case depends in a large part on why callers are calling your code and what they expect in return for such a degenerate case.  I'd say you should return floating-point infinity and leave it to the caller to sort out the details.